# html file path not linking to file

Tags: html, .htaccess

Ok, I consistently have this problem and I'm sure it's probably simple and stupid.

```
Folder Structure:
 -pages>gallerys>events.php
  index.php
```

Example:

I'm on `index.php` in the root folder trying to link to `events.php`.

The link I use in the navbar is linked to `pages/gallerys/events.php` and yet I keep getting a 404 error.

I've also tried `/pages/gallerys/events.php`.

Nothing works.

Link example:

```
<li><a href="./pages/gallerys/events.php">Seminars/Special Events</a></li>
```

UPDATE:

Ok, I think I see the problem, and I'm hoping I can explain it enough.

I was wrong, I do have some php and I don't believe I forgot.

My navigation bar is in a separate file and I include it on the page with a php include.

I'm gonna play with it and see what happens. If I get it working or not I'll report back.

Comment: Are you trying to access the file on some server? i.e. Linking from `http://example.com/index.php` to `http://example.com/pages/gallerys/events.php`? In this case, see if the file is actually there

Comment: Yes, this is the case. And the file is right where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Do you have a code example of what you're doing right now?

Comment: I placed the current link code in the main post, if that is what you meant

Comment: Looks like the link you provided in the comment in the answer below is throwing an error 500. There might be an error in your PHP, but the file seems to be there, otherwise it would be an error 404. Also: Your code example should, in theory, work, even without the leading dot.

Comment: I don't have any php in the project yet.

Comment: Then maybe it's some server config error, but the file seems to be there. Could you try to have a look at some log files of the server? Maybe you find the error there.

Comment: I don't see anything in the error logs. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "./pages/gallerys/events.php" ?

Comment: Nothing.

I even tried manually going to the page through the url

http://project8.byethost22.com/pages/gallerys/events.php and up comes a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.php`, add at the top of your file the following line :

`printf("Current working directory : %s <br />", getcwd());`

[PHP: **getcwd** - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

It will display the current path to your directory.

Do the same to in your file `events.php`, and you will figure out how to call you correct URL.

Sometimes, depending on the web host, your directory root name may vary.

Comment: Ok, I did it. The file is at the path I thought it should be.

Comment: So now you may reach the file you need by comparing the filepath for `index.php` and the one for the file `events.php` isn't it ?

Comment: I'm not sure how. According to the information I got, my link should work as it is.